# How big a set can we get from this construction?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Construct a set $X\subset (0,1)$ likewise:

- Consider some irrational $x$ in $(0,1)$ which we represent in base $2$ e.g. $x=0.\,m_1m_2\,...$ where $m_i\in\{0,1\}$ for all $i$. Add it to $X$.
- Consider another irrational $x'\in (0,1)$ and choose $S=\{s_1,\, s_2,\cdots\}\subset \mathbb{N}$ such that $x'=0.\,m_{s_1}m_{s_2}\,\ldots$ and add it to $X$.
- Consider another irrational $x''\in (0,1)$ and choose $S'=\{s'_1,\, s'_2,\ldots\}\subset S$ such that $x''=0.\,m_{s'_1}m_{s'_2}\,\ldots$ and add it to $X$.

etc.

Am I correct in saying that the end set $X=\{x,x',\, ...\}$ will be countable? Is there any way to amend this construction so that we end up with an uncountable set?

> The intial question was to find a chain $\mathbb{N}\supset S\supset S'\supset \cdots,$ if there is one, such that $\Sigma =\{\mathbb{N},S,S',\,\ldots\}$ is not countable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial question has a much simpler solution. The process that you suggest seem to end up with a countable set simply because you define this process by induction, but you don't say what happens after we exhausted all the finite indices.

For that purpose we have ordinals, which generalize the natural numbers to the transfinite. This allows us to use induction and recursion longer than just the natural numbers themselves, and indeed we can do induction with uncountably many steps. But for that you need to say what happens when you reach a limit point, i.e. when you exhausted all the available "immediate next step"'s.

Whether or not your idea can be carried over, I cannot say. I'm not fully sure that I understand what is it that you are trying to do. Note that you don't even describe the process right. It would be as if you were telling me something like this:

> Consider the sequence $a_0=1, a_1=50, a_2=\pi,$ etc. Does it converge?

It's hard to say what should $a_3$ be, or if there is a general formula for the sequence. Instead you should say exactly what is the process. Something like this:

> We begin with $x\in(0,1)$. We do [...]; suppose that we have defined a set $S$, if there is some $x'\in(0,1)$ such that [...] then we do [...].

Now we can claim that $S$ is uncountable, for example, by showing that no countably many elements exhaust the process of definition.

But let me give you a hint for the solution of the actual problem: the rational numbers are countable, and they are dense in $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Thank you. Following your hint, would something along these lines be acceptable? Set up a bijection $\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{Q}$. Define for $x>0,\;A_x=\{q\in \mathbb{Q}:\;|q|<x\}$. Then for any $A_x,A_y$ either $A_x\subset A_y$ or $A_y\subset A_x$ and the set $\Sigma=\{A_x:\;x\in\mathbb{R}^{+}\}$ is uncountable.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was a nice hint.